# Asterisk - Digium fax for asterisk add-on - receive fax?

Tags: asterisk, fax

I'm new in the world of VOIP and all what is related to it.

Playing around with asterisk in combination with the Digium fax for asterisk add-on (https://www.digium.com/products/software/fax-for-asterisk) resulted in a working flow in combination with SIP. So I'm able to receive faxes using the SIP configs, but now I want to switch to a different setup.

A Cisco voicegateway is configured to redirect a specific number to the asterisk server

```
voice translation-profile to_asterisk
 translate called 2


dial-peer voice 590 voip
 description to esker-fax (xxx/xxx.590)
 translation-profile outgoing to_asterisk
 preference 1
 destination-pattern 32XXXXXX590
 voice-class h323 1
 session target ipv4:10.242.15.51
 dtmf-relay h245-alphanumeric
 codec g711alaw
 fax protocol t38 ls-redundancy 0 hs-redundancy 0 fallback pass-through g711alaw
 no vad
```

Sending a fax to the 32XXXXXX590 doesn't show any log on the asterisk server. Obviously there is some configuration that needs to be done, but I have no idea what I should change. Due to my little to no knowledge of this matter, it is hard to use search results on Google.

Therefore I would like to ask if there is someone out there that can help me to clarify some things and finalize the setup.

Asterisk 11.17.0 on CentOS 6.7 final

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Use tcpdump too see if it ever come on server. If it not, it is not asterisk's question

Comment: I ran a TCP dump and see some traffic. I'm not sure how to recognize this specific traffic. During the capture I've done two calls to the number. And I see there are 2 similar flows. both to port 1720.

Answer (score 0):

So most likly your cisco work  to port 1720 not 5060. You  have change IOS too new version or port for sip in sip.conf to 1720(may have other issues with providers)

Comment: I've changed the port in the sip.conf, but this has no result. When I run 'astersik -rvvvvv' and run 'core set verbose 99', I do not see anything when a new call arrives.

Comment: You have use tcpdump and sip debug. Verbose will not help here. debug is OT here.

Comment: I've configured the SIP on 1720, enabled the SIP debug and rang the number. Nothing in the asterisk CLI. I also send a fax to the number, but nothing in the SIP debug. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Update cisco IOS to latest posible, contact cisco support.

Comment: What I find strange is that I have to use the SIP config file. The CISCO is only action as a IP forward and not maintaining a SIP trunk.

Comment: Do you have some more suggestions ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hire expert(or change device to more user-friendly)